# OS X El Capitan mail folder issue

Tags: macos, mail.app

I upgraded my Macbook Pro this morning to Version 10.11, and all my personal mail folders disappeared with up to 24 months of archived and must needed emails.  They still show up on my iPhone 6...and I'm getting iCloud flow between the two.  How do I get them to reappear on my Mac?  Help?

Comment: try http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/174732/85275

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked (but Synchronise is under Mailbox not Messages)

Answer (score 1):

It is a common issue, your data did not disappear. Just go to the tab "Mailbox" in Apple mail and than click "Synchronize". All your mails will be downloaded from the servers they were on.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work.