# Mail.app with El Capitan displays message titles in undersized width

Tags: mail.app, macos

After I upgraded to OS X 10.11 (currently running 10.11.1), messages are no longer properly displayed in Mail.app: [image: screenshot]

All message information is crammed into a space with minimum width, despite the fact that the actual column width is much larger.
Resizing the column temporarily restores a correct display but the problem comes back as soon as I switch to another mailbox.

Of course restarting the application, or the computer itself, did not help.
I have not seen this problem documented elsewhere. Is it only me?

Comment: Maybe try switching to Classic view, relaunching & switching back.

Comment: @tetsujin - Thank you for your suggestion. In fact, I had already tried it before, but switching to Classic view causes Mail to crash at startup. I was lucky to succeed opening the preference pane fast enough to uncheck the option, but this took me back to the same point.
This behavior likely indicates that there is something damaged in my mail system, possibly in some configuration file, but I am afraid of losing messages stored locally if I try to reset the Mail library folder.

Comment: Have a look at my answer here for how to reset mail without losing anything - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174727/mail-app-crashes-constantly-even-after-deleting-mail-profile-and-cache/174732#174732

Comment: @tetsujin - I will try your suggestion when I have some time, but it seems to ma that it more likely to affect the _content_ of mailboxes than the _layout_ of the main message visualization window.

Comment: possibly - but it's a lossless process. After that you're down to trashing the prefs etc, which is likely to be more disruptive

Comment: @jmichel
I have the same display problem and I, too have not seen any other documentation of it. I have it on two computers, an iMac and a MacBook Air. Interestingly, another user on the iMac does not have that problem. I tried deleting preferences and envelope files to reimport all mails and reindex them, but nothing helped. Have you meanwhile solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the folder ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail

You may have to re-enter some preferences. I use MailTags and had to re-enter license data and preference information.

Comment: I had missed this reply at time it was posted. I have just tried the suggestion and it _did_ solve my problem. Thanks a lot.